# How do you map a Map<String,MyObject> using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, dictionary

I've got a requirement for an application to log customer interactions to a DB the customer interactions have several default fields like: time, interation type, customer id. But they also need to be able to hold arbitrary customer specific data.

In code I want to host the data as a map of the form Map where the key is a string with the name of the data item, and the Data is an object that has the data value and maybe some meta data like how to render it, or how to search on it.

The way I see this in the DB is having a table of the interactions and another table with all the attached data, with a column in the attached data table telling me which interation the data related to.

Something like:
Interaction_Table:
id, interactionDate, customerId, interactionType.

Attached_Data_Table:
id, interactionId, dataName, dataValue, dataType.

What is the best way to map this out in Hibernate, I've tried looking at docs for mapping Maps but it doesn't make sense to me (Possibly too early in the day).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's one to many relation, [Here](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/09/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping.html) You will find a very detailed example.

Comment: While that works for putting the data into the DB I'd rather have the data as a Hashtable in code so I can easily look it up.